# Problemas al obtener datos después de hacer innerjoin haciendo uso de EF en ASP.CORE NET

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework

Una de las opciones que tengo es obtener la informacion concerniente a un paciente "X" previa selección, funciona al 100% pero posteriormente en base a una necesidad debo de mostrar el nombre del doctor que lo atiende y tuve que añadir un inner join el cual funciona y me trae la informacion el problema que no me habia percatado que si realizo otra selección que no sea la primera me trae siempre los mismos datos del primer registro.

Mi clase Modelo_Paciente

```
    public class MODELO_PACIENTE
    {
        #region TBL_PACIENTE
        [Key]
        public int PAC_ID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        [Required]
        public string PAC_CODIGO { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "El Nombre mínimo es de {2} caracteres")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ$@!#? ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Letras")]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre(S) Paciente")]
        public String PAC_NOMBRE { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Apellido del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "El Apellido mínimo es de {2} caracteres")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ$@!#? ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Letras")]
        [Display(Name = "Apellido(S) Paciente")]
        public String PAC_APELLIDO { get; set; }
        public String PAC_SEXO { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El RUT es Obligatorio")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{1,10}$", ErrorMessage = "El RUT es de 10 digitos númericos")]
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength =10, ErrorMessage = "El RUT mínimo es de {2} dígitos númericos")]
        public String PAC_RUT { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Fecha de Nacimiento del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd-MM-yyyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime PAC_FECHA_NAC { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Edad del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        [Range(minimum: 5,maximum:90, ErrorMessage = "La Edad debe estar entre {1} y {2} años")]
        public int PAC_EDAD { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "El Nombre del Representante mínimo es de {2} caracteres")]
        public String PAC_REPRESENTANTE { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "La Dirección mínimo es de {2} caracteres")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Dirección del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        public String PAC_DIRECCION { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Comuna del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        public String PAC_COMUNA { get; set; }

        public String PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS { get; set; }

        public String PAC_TELEFONO { get; set; }

        
        public String PAC_CORREO { get; set; }
    
        public String PAC_CONVENIO { get; set; }

        public String PAC_PREVISIONES { get; set; }

        public String PAC_OBSERVACIONES { get; set; }
      
        public String PAC_COD_ODONT { get; set; }

        public byte[] PAC_IMAGEN { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime PAC_FEC_REG { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime PAC_FEC_ACT { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        [NotMapped]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
       
    #endregion
}
```

Este es mi primer codigo.

```
    public List<MODELO_PACIENTE> get_Pacientes_Async(String valor, int id)
        {
            List<MODELO_PACIENTE> ListaTPacientes;
            var PacienteLista = new List<MODELO_PACIENTE>();
            if (valor == null && id.Equals(0))
            {
                ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.OrderBy(u => u.PAC_ID).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                if (id.Equals(0))
                {
                    ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
                }
            }
            if (!ListaTPacientes.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                foreach (var item in ListaTPacientes)
                {
                    PacienteLista.Add(new MODELO_PACIENTE
                    {
                        PAC_ID = item.PAC_ID,
                        PAC_RUT = item.PAC_RUT,
                        PAC_CODIGO = item.PAC_CODIGO,
                        PAC_COD_ODONT = item.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                        PAC_FECHA_NAC = item.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                        PAC_FEC_ACT = item.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                        PAC_FEC_REG = item.PAC_FEC_REG,
                        PAC_NOMBRE = item.PAC_NOMBRE,
                        PAC_APELLIDO = item.PAC_APELLIDO,
                        PAC_CORREO = item.PAC_CORREO,
                        PAC_TELEFONO = item.PAC_TELEFONO,
                        PAC_COMUNA = item.PAC_COMUNA,
                        PAC_DIRECCION = item.PAC_DIRECCION,
                        PAC_CONVENIO = item.PAC_CONVENIO,
                        PAC_OBSERVACIONES = item.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                        PAC_EDAD = item.PAC_EDAD,
                        PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = item.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                        PAC_PREVISIONES = item.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                        PAC_REPRESENTANTE = item.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                        PAC_SEXO = item.PAC_SEXO,
                        PAC_IMAGEN = item.PAC_IMAGEN,
                    }
);
                }
            }
            return PacienteLista;
        }
```

Este es el segundo codigo.

```
      public List<MODELO_PACIENTE> get_Pacientes_Async(string valor, int id)
    {
                var PacienteLista = new List<MODELO_PACIENTE>();
       
            var ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.Join(_context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO, p => p.PAC_COD_ODONT, o => o.ODONT_CODIGO
      , (p, o) => new
      {
          p.PAC_ID,
          p.PAC_CODIGO,
          p.PAC_NOMBRE,
          p.PAC_APELLIDO,
          p.PAC_SEXO,
          p.PAC_RUT,
          p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
          p.PAC_EDAD,
          p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
          p.PAC_DIRECCION,
          p.PAC_COMUNA,
          p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
          p.PAC_TELEFONO,
          p.PAC_CORREO,
          p.PAC_CONVENIO,
          p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
          p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
          p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
          p.PAC_IMAGEN,
          p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
          p.PAC_FEC_REG,
          o.ODONT_CODIGO,
          o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
          o.ODONT_NOMBRE
      }).OrderBy(u => u.PAC_ID).ToList();
      
            var query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor) ? ListaTPacientes
                 : id.Equals(0) ? ListaTPacientes.Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList() : ListaTPacientes.Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
      
        if (!ListaTPacientes.Count.Equals(0))
        {
            foreach (var item in ListaTPacientes)
            {
                PacienteLista.Add(new MODELO_PACIENTE
                {
                    PAC_ID = item.PAC_ID,
                    PAC_RUT = item.PAC_RUT,
                    PAC_CODIGO = item.PAC_CODIGO,
                    PAC_COD_ODONT = item.PAC_COD_ODONT + '-' + item.ODONT_APELLIDO + ' ' + item.ODONT_NOMBRE,
                    PAC_FECHA_NAC = item.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                    PAC_FEC_ACT = item.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                    PAC_FEC_REG = item.PAC_FEC_REG,
                    PAC_NOMBRE = item.PAC_NOMBRE,
                    PAC_APELLIDO = item.PAC_APELLIDO,
                    PAC_CORREO = item.PAC_CORREO,
                    PAC_TELEFONO = item.PAC_TELEFONO,
                    PAC_COMUNA = item.PAC_COMUNA,
                    PAC_DIRECCION = item.PAC_DIRECCION,
                    PAC_CONVENIO = item.PAC_CONVENIO,
                    PAC_OBSERVACIONES = item.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                    PAC_EDAD = item.PAC_EDAD,
                    PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = item.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                    PAC_PREVISIONES = item.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                    PAC_REPRESENTANTE = item.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                    PAC_SEXO = item.PAC_SEXO,
                    PAC_IMAGEN = item.PAC_IMAGEN,
                });
            }

        }
        return PacienteLista;
    }
```

Y mi clase Detalle en la cual en mi método `OnGet` realizo el llamado del método correspondiente

```
  public void OnGet(int id) //Pasar el id a través de la variable PAC_ID del Paciente para proceder a ver el detalle
    {
        var Data = _lPaciente.get_Pacientes_Async(null, id);
        if (0 < Data.Count)
        {
            MODEL_PACIENTE = new PACIENTE
            {
                DataPaciente = Data.ToList().Last(),
            };
        }
    }
```

Que estaría realizando erróneamente que no me permite realizar en mi segundo código tener la obtención de los datos correctamente?.

Comment: Esto es Entity Framework no? faltaria esa etiqueta? y sobran algunas de asp.net no?

Comment: Le añadí la etiquetas de `Entity Framewrok`, sabes como podría resolver mi dilema?

Comment: no se nada de EF yo...

Comment: y aquí murió mi esperanza jaja, tocara seguir googleando, igual gracias por tu tiempo !

Comment: Si tienes una relación directa, ¿por qué no mejor un include?

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo de include?, anteriormente en c# lo hacia obteniendo los datos a través de un sp y listo pero aquí al parecer el panorama es un poco distinto para la obtención de los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

planteo una solución que por funcionalidad se ejecuta al 100% pero creería que por codificación no seria lo correcto.

Si alguien tiene otra manera de pensar o ayudarme a mejorar el código se lo agradecería.

```
var ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                  join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      p.PAC_ID,
                                      p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                      p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                      p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                      p.PAC_SEXO,
                                      p.PAC_RUT,
                                      p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                      p.PAC_EDAD,
                                      p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                      p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                      p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                      p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                      p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                      p.PAC_CORREO,
                                      p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                      p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                      p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                      p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                      p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                      o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                      o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                      o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                  }).OrderBy(u => u.PAC_ID).ToList();
            if (valor == null && id.Equals(0))
            {
                ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                  join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      p.PAC_ID,
                                      p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                      p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                      p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                      p.PAC_SEXO,
                                      p.PAC_RUT,
                                      p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                      p.PAC_EDAD,
                                      p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                      p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                      p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                      p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                      p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                      p.PAC_CORREO,
                                      p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                      p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                      p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                      p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                      p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                      o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                      o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                      o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                  }).OrderBy(u => u.PAC_ID).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                if (id.Equals(0))
                {
                    //   var query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor) ? ListaTPaciente
                    //: id.Equals(0) ? ListaTPaciente.Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList() : ListaTPaciente.Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
                    ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                      join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          p.PAC_ID,
                                          p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                          p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                          p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                          p.PAC_SEXO,
                                          p.PAC_RUT,
                                          p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                          p.PAC_EDAD,
                                          p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                          p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                          p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                          p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                          p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                          p.PAC_CORREO,
                                          p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                          p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                          p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                          p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                          p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                          o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                          o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                          o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                      }).Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                      join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          p.PAC_ID,
                                          p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                          p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                          p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                          p.PAC_SEXO,
                                          p.PAC_RUT,
                                          p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                          p.PAC_EDAD,
                                          p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                          p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                          p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                          p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                          p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                          p.PAC_CORREO,
                                          p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                          p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                          p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                          p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                          p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                          o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                          o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                          o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                      }).Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
                }
            }

            if (!ListaTPaciente.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                foreach (var item in ListaTPaciente)
                {
                    PacienteLista.Add(new MODELO_PACIENTE
                    {
                        PAC_ID = item.PAC_ID,
                        PAC_RUT = item.PAC_RUT,
                        PAC_CODIGO = item.PAC_CODIGO,
                        PAC_COD_ODONT = item.PAC_COD_ODONT + '-' + item.ODONT_APELLIDO + ' ' + item.ODONT_NOMBRE,
                        PAC_FECHA_NAC = item.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                        PAC_FEC_ACT = item.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                        PAC_FEC_REG = item.PAC_FEC_REG,
                        PAC_NOMBRE = item.PAC_NOMBRE,
                        PAC_APELLIDO = item.PAC_APELLIDO,
                        PAC_CORREO = item.PAC_CORREO,
                        PAC_TELEFONO = item.PAC_TELEFONO,
                        PAC_COMUNA = item.PAC_COMUNA,
                        PAC_DIRECCION = item.PAC_DIRECCION,
                        PAC_CONVENIO = item.PAC_CONVENIO,
                        PAC_OBSERVACIONES = item.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                        PAC_EDAD = item.PAC_EDAD,
                        PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = item.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                        PAC_PREVISIONES = item.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                        PAC_REPRESENTANTE = item.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                        PAC_SEXO = item.PAC_SEXO,
                        PAC_IMAGEN = item.PAC_IMAGEN,
                    });
                }

            }
        
        return PacienteLista;
```